# How to create regexp which select digits between ()?

Tags: php, regex

I have a lot of string which can contain a digit sequence between () like:

Some text 123 (some text in brackets, may contain digits) (12345678)

Some text 123 - is required part

(some text in brackets, may contain digits) - is not required

(12345678) - is not required and must be deleted.

Real exmple:

"Project name - part name (stage2) (123123)"

I have next regexp `[(\d)]` but it will delete "(2)" from (stage2) and "(123123)". I need to delete ONLY "(123123)". How I can modify my regexp for this?

Comment: Use `preg_replace('~\(\d+\)~', '', $string)` to remove `(digits_here)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Wiktor Stribizew is right.

replace

```
[(\d)]
```

with

```
\(\d+\)
```

test it here: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem, correct regexp is `[ ][(][\d]*[)]`

Comment: Why all these character class?